# C-c C-k is undefined in Emacs24

Tags: emacs, clojure, nrepl

I have installed Emacs24,and installed clojure-mode nrepl. 
I opened a emacs window, and M-x nrepl-jack-in, it shows:
; nrepl.el 0.2.0 (Cljoure 1.6.0, nREPL 0.2.3)

I open a clj buffer in another window, I want to compile the buffer file by using C-c,C-K, but I get C-c, C-k is undefined.

How can I get it work to compile the clj file. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you're up to date; CIDER has replaced NREPL.el for a while now, and has just had a major update. See https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider